# Pandas - MS SQL - import and error handling tracking into log file

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

First of all, I would like to take this opportunity to wish everyone from this wonderful community a happy, safe and sparkling new year - as a French guy, I would say enjoy good champagne (with moderation) if you are stuck at home as I am.

**Here is what I am trying to do.**

using Pyodbc, I connect to my db (MS SQL server 2019) and load a subset (3000 lines) of a large CSV file (millions lines). it goes fine but there are errors and the upload is roll backed as there are some shenanigans ...

**What I did**

I used SSM to load the subset file and discovered 10 rows were having data quality issues. I fixed and reloaded successfully

**what I would like to do**

I would like to load the file and when the insert cause an issue

1. Trace the entry with the issue ( line number or total line) into an error tracking file and skip to next entry to try to load it into SQL - at the end I will have (for example) 2950 entries in my table and 50 rows in my tracking files.

is this doable using python/pandas/pyodbc/...

thank!

Comment: I would think on two approaches , one is to do the validations prior to inserting it to the DB, the 2nd think if you don't mind about performance is to loop over each record and use try and except

Comment: Thanks Nir ! sounds like a plan. May I ask how you would validate prior inserting? is this a native python or Pyodbc function ?

Comment: Looping on the records prior to insert will be faster then trying to insert them 1 by 1, and you can convert the fields to the datatypes you want